# Javascript Quantity Validation Multiple Inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and still learn. I just want to ask how to make code validation for more than one input? I have data table item. I want to run validation input for each row.

[image]

My Code below is only run for the first row, and cannot running in the second row.

```
<tr>
  <td><input id="stock" type="number" name="stock" value="<?php echo $row->stock; ?>" readonly></td>
  <td><input id="qty" onInput="calc();" type="number" name="qty"></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(){
        var stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;

        if(qty > stock){
            alert("Qty More Than Stock!");
            document.getElementById("qty").value = 1;
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with an `data-attribute` for select all `inputs` then `forEach` it and check the value like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[data-check]').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(el.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].value)) {
      alert("Qty More Than Stock!");
      el.value = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="stock" type="number" name="stock" value="2" readonly></td>
    <td><input data-check type="number" name="qty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="stock" type="number" name="stock" value="3" readonly></td>
    <td><input data-check type="number" name="qty"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PS. Remember to use always a structure like my example else my code probably doesn't work.
in fact `el.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].value` it's like say: element - parent of element (td) - previous element (other td) - the first children of the previus element (input).

---

Another option is use another data-attribute for select the stock value like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[data-check]').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let stock = document.querySelector('input[data-index="'+el.dataset.stock+'"]');
    if (parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(stock.value)) {
      alert("Qty More Than Stock!");
      el.value = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-index='0' type="number" name="stock" value="2" readonly></td>
    <td><input data-check data-stock='0' type="number" name="qty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-index='1' type="number" name="stock" value="25" readonly></td>
    <td><input data-check data-stock='1' type="number" name="qty"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks before for your help, but it's not working. The still working forfirst row, cannot running for the next row.  The data is from foreach database table.

Comment: Use the second example that must work with all structure. (as you can see if work here can work everywhere )

Comment: The second not working if th value of stock more than 10. Validation running in input value qty 2. And then if stock 20, validation running in input value 3 ? It should running if qty value 11 and 21.

Comment: Can you post complete code ? so i can see your error. Obv you changed the index and stock in all inputs?

Comment: the problem is almost solve, just confuse why alert running when I input value >= 2 if stock 10? And input value >=3 if stock 20. But I can input value <= 5 If stock 5. I have to change Type data number ? How to change type data number in javascript.

Comment: I try to change value from your second code = 25,
<td><input id="stock" data-index='0' type="number" name="stock" value="25" readonly></td>
Alert running when I input qty value more than = 3

Comment: You have right, i add `parseInt()` for the value try now.

Comment: Thank you simone for your help.. I appreciate. :)